# Inequality in Cauchy criterion for Real-valued series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[Rudin Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve9dI.png)
I have a question about inequality shown in image(I can't post inline images, sorry). Since the series under consideration are real-valued, being convergent sequence or cauchy sequence is equivalent. So let $s_n=\sum a_n$ By Rudin, we have: $\forall\epsilon\gt0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\ge m\ge N: |\sum_{k=m}^na_k |= |s_n-s_m| \le \epsilon$.

So my question is: why does Rudin states "**$\le$**" rather than "$\lt$" even though cauchy sequence require "$\lt$"

Comment: I believe that Rudin did that because when taking limits $<$ become $\leq$.

Answer (score 1):

Why does he do that? I doubt that anyone knows. But it's important to note that it doesn't matter, and it's important to understand why it's more or less obvious that it doesn't matter, because analogous issues arise. So:

> > **Def.** $(s_n)$ is *weakly Cauchy* if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ so $|s_n-s_m|\le\epsilon$ for all $n,m>N$.

> > **Def.** $(s_n)$ is *strongly Cauchy* if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ so $|s_n-s_m|<\epsilon$ for all $n,m>N$.

> > **Important Triviality.** $(s_n)$ is weakly Cauchy if and only if it is strongly Cauchy.

Proof: For the less trivial direction, suppose $(s_n)$ is weakly Cauchy and $\epsilon>0$ . Since $\epsilon/2>0$ there exists $N$ such that $|s_n-s_m|\le\epsilon/2$ for all $n,m>N$. Hence $|s_n-s_m|<\epsilon$ for all $n,m>N$.